# Insert an item into sorted list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm creating a class where one of the methods inserts a new item into the sorted list. The item is inserted in the corrected (sorted) position in the sorted list. I'm not allowed to use any built-in list functions or methods other than `[]`, `[:]`, `+`, and `len` though. This is the part that's really confusing to me.

What would be the best way in going about this?

Comment: Homework? You would probably start by searching the Web how to insert elements into a sorted list.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use and built-in list functions though

Comment: @FelixKling the OP stated that the disallowance of [`.insert()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) is what makes it confusing for the OP. Not very expectable for any amount of search to find anyone a good focus on this in the particular context.

Comment: use binary search to find the index to insert

Answer (score 216):

Use the [insort](http://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html?highlight=insort#bisect.insort) function of the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect 
a = [1, 2, 4, 5] 
bisect.insort(a, 3) 
print(a)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For more complicated usage, check `key` parameter for `insort` method

```py
import bisect
a = [{"key": 1}, {"key": 3}]
bisect.insort(a, {"key": 2}, key=lambda x: x["key"])
print(a)
```

Output

```
[{"key": 1}, {"key": 2}, {"key": 3}]
```

Comment: Missing what to do, when items are not integers. I.e. how can I use it in real world problem?

Comment: @Velda here's a non-integer example: `s = ['a', 'b', 'd']; bisect.insort(s, 'c'); assert(s == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`

Comment: Still integer example. And btw., how often do you sort letters...? What if I want to sort instances of some class by some property of it?

Comment: @Velda I think the last example of bisect documentation might be useful. Also you may adjust the code of bisect.insort a bit just like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41903429/7708392

Comment: @Velda if you're comparing custom classes, you can implement the \_\_lt\_\_ method and bisect.insort wil be able to correctly sort class instances.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__lt__

Comment: @drakenation Out of curiosity how did you come across this information, because I did not glean this from the documentation and want to become more effective and finding such information on my own.

Comment: @Filip Gajowniczek If you try sorting custom classes using sorted(), you'll get "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'MyClasss' and 'MyClasss'", which means that if you implement \_\_lt\_\_, you can use sorted(). I expected bisect.insort to have the same behavior, so I tested and it worked. My tips are: try stuff out, pay attention to error messages and search for possible solutions.

Comment: This runs in O(n). It's not algorithmically better than simply scanning through the list, finding the appropriate positions, and reshuffling the elements in the list to maintain the sorted order

Comment: Thanks @nz_21, was looking for a way to do sorted data insertion without needing to implement a BST. Doesn't suit the OP's answer but using a [library](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers/) could work and perform insertion at O(log(N)). Or cop the O(N) insertion complexity.

Comment: @nz_21 Actually I think that this solution is technically O(log(n) + n) --> log(n) to search for the position, and n to insert. The solution you described would be O(n + n) --> n to search for the position, and n to insert. So bisect is slightly faster I believe

Comment: @ionox0 No. In terms of asymptotic complexity, `O(log(n) + n)= O(n)`

Comment: @nz_21 The way ionox0 wrote *"O(log(n) + n) --> log(n)"* is confusing. The arrow should be a period. They mean *O(n)* overall.

Comment: @Velda, also, except `__lt__`, since python 3.10 you can also pass `key=` argument to `insort` or `bisect`

Answer (score 88):

Hint 1:  You might want to study the Python code in the [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/bisect.html#module-bisect).

Hint 2:  [Slicing](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) can be used for list insertion:

```
>>> s = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']
>>> s[2:2] = ['c']
>>> s
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Since OP wasn't allowed to use any functions or methods, slicing is left as  the only way to insert a new element into a list.

Comment: bisect is nice for sorted list insertions, but it falls down to O(N) in speed, because it uses python's base lists. Is there anything on the market with linked lists or something like that?

Comment: @MaksimGayduk Try the blist module at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/1.3.6 .  That said, the OP for this post has some fairly strict limitations on which tools were allowed to be used.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Or basic techniques like looping through the list and moving items or copying to another list. That might be what they wanted OP to learn.

Comment: @Jacktose.  If you have an answer to post, please do so.  Otherwise, the snark isn't appreciated and borders on being abusive and condescending.

FWIW, my reading of the OP's question indicated that the list needed to be modified in-place and without using list methods. Even if a new list was allow, the OP had no direct way to build one with only `[]`, `[:]`, `+`, and `len`.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger No snark, and apologies if I offended you—I'm a big fan!
I guess that OP's teacher may have wanted them to learn some very basics of list manipulation, and I don't read the question to prohibit something like `for i in len(old): if i<item: new[i]=old[i] ...`. However, it didn't occur to me that that was worth an answer.

Answer (score 40):

You should use the bisect module. Also, the list needs to be sorted before using bisect.insort_left

It's a pretty big difference.

```
>>> l = [0, 2, 4, 5, 9]
>>> bisect.insort_left(l,8)
>>> l
[0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]

timeit.timeit("l.append(8); l = sorted(l)",setup="l = [4,2,0,9,5]; import bisect; l = sorted(l)",number=10000)
    1.2235019207000732

timeit.timeit("bisect.insort_left(l,8)",setup="l = [4,2,0,9,5]; import bisect; l=sorted(l)",number=10000)
    0.041441917419433594
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm learning Algorithm right now, so i wonder how bisect module writes.
Here is the code from bisect module about inserting an item into sorted list, which uses dichotomy:

```
def insort_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Insert item x in list a, and keep it sorted assuming a is sorted.
    If x is already in a, insert it to the right of the rightmost x.
    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid+1
    a.insert(lo, x)
```

Answer (score 6):

If there are no artificial restrictions, **`bisect.insort()`** should be used as [described by `stanga`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001030/4540114). However, as `Velda` mentioned in a comment, most real-world problems go beyond sorting pure numbers.

Fortunately, as commented by `drakenation`, the solution **applies to any comparable objects**. For example, `bisect.insort()` also works with a custom dataclass that implements `__lt__()`:

```
from bisect import insort

@dataclass
class Person:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    age: int

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.age < other.age

persons = []

insort(persons, Person('John', 'Doe', 30))
insort(persons, Person('Jane', 'Doe', 28))
insort(persons, Person('Santa', 'Claus', 1750))

# [Person(first_name='Jane', last_name='Doe', age=28), Person(first_name='John', last_name='Doe', age=30), Person(first_name='Santa', last_name='Claus', age=1750)]
```

However, **in the case of tuples, it would be desirable to sort by an arbitrary key**. By default, tuples are sorted by their first item (first name), then by the next item (last name), and so on.

As a solution you can **manage an additional list of keys**:

```
from bisect import bisect

persons = []
ages = []

def insert_person(person):
    age = person[2]
    i = bisect(ages, age)
    persons.insert(i, person)
    ages.insert(i, age)
    
insert_person(('John', 'Doe', 30))
insert_person(('Jane', 'Doe', 28))
insert_person(('Santa', 'Claus', 1750))
```

**Official solution**: The [documentation of `bisect.insort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort) refers to a [**recipe**](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/) how to use the function to implement this functionality in a **custom class `SortedCollection`**, so that it can be used as follows:

```
>>> s = SortedCollection(key=itemgetter(2))
>>> for record in [
...         ('roger', 'young', 30),
...         ('angela', 'jones', 28),
...         ('bill', 'smith', 22),
...         ('david', 'thomas', 32)]:
...     s.insert(record)

>>> pprint(list(s))         # show records sorted by age
[('bill', 'smith', 22),
 ('angela', 'jones', 28),
 ('roger', 'young', 30),
 ('david', 'thomas', 32)]
```

Following is the relevant extract of the class required to make the example work. Basically, the `SortedCollection` **manages an additional list of keys** in parallel to the items list to find out where to insert the new tuple (and its key).

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class SortedCollection(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable=(), key=None):
        self._given_key = key
        key = (lambda x: x) if key is None else key
        decorated = sorted((key(item), item) for item in iterable)
        self._keys = [k for k, item in decorated]
        self._items = [item for k, item in decorated]
        self._key = key
        
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self._items[i]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._items)
        
    def insert(self, item):
        'Insert a new item.  If equal keys are found, add to the left'
        k = self._key(item)
        i = bisect_left(self._keys, k)
        self._keys.insert(i, k)
        self._items.insert(i, item)
```

**Note** that `list.insert()` as well as `bisect.insort()` have **O(n)** complexity. Thus, as commented by `nz_21`, manually iterating through the sorted list, looking for the right position, would be just as good in terms of complexity. In fact, simply sorting the array after inserting a new value will probably be fine, too, since Python's [Timsort has a worst-case complexity of O(n log(n))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). For completeness, however, note that a binary search tree (BST) would allow insertions in O(log(n)) time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution for you:

```
a = [15, 12, 10]
b = sorted(a)
print b # --> b = [10, 12, 15]
c = 13
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] > c:
        break
d = b[:i] + [c] + b[i:]
print d # --> d = [10, 12, 13, 15]
```

Comment: Not the best solution, the `bisect` module would find the insertion point in O(log n) steps, your's potentially has to search the whole list, O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
# function to insert a number in an sorted list


def pstatement(value_returned):
    return print('new sorted list =', value_returned)


def insert(input, n):
    print('input list = ', input)
    print('number to insert = ', n)
    print('range to iterate is =', len(input))

    first = input[0]
    print('first element =', first)
    last = input[-1]
    print('last element =', last)

    if first > n:
        list = [n] + input[:]
        return pstatement(list)
    elif last < n:
        list = input[:] + [n]
        return pstatement(list)
    else:
        for i in range(len(input)):
            if input[i] > n:
                break
    list = input[:i] + [n] + input[i:]
    return pstatement(list)

# Input values
listq = [2, 4, 5]
n = 1

insert(listq, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many ways to do this, here is a simple naive program to do the same using inbuilt Python function sorted()

```
def sorted_inserter():
list_in = []
n1 = int(input("How many items in the list : "))

for i in range (n1):
    e1 = int(input("Enter numbers in list : "))
    list_in.append(e1)
print("The input list is : ",list_in)


print("Any more items to be inserted ?")
n2 = int(input("How many more numbers to be added ? : "))
for j in range (n2):
    e2= int(input("Add more numbers : "))
    list_in.append(e2)
    list_sorted=sorted(list_in)
    print("The sorted list is: ",list_sorted)
    

sorted_inserter()
```

The output is

How many items in the list : 4

Enter numbers in list : 1

Enter numbers in list : 2

Enter numbers in list : 123

Enter numbers in list : 523

The input list is :  [1, 2, 123, 523]

Any more items to be inserted ?

How many more numbers to be added ? : 1

Add more numbers : 9

The sorted list is:  [1, 2, 9, 123, 523]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers: When you want to insert an element into a list of tuples where the first element is comparable and the second is not you can use the `key` parameter of the `bisect.insort` function as follows:

```
import bisect 

class B:
    pass

a = [(1, B()), (2, B()), (3, B())] 
bisect.insort(a, (3, B()), key=lambda x: x[0]) 
print(a)
```

Without the `lambda` function as the third parameter of the `bisect.insort` function the code would throw a `TypeError` as the function would try to compare the second element of a tuple as a tie breaker which isn't comparable by default.

Answer (score -9):

This is the best way to append the list and insert values to sorted list:

```
 a = [] num = int(input('How many numbers: ')) for n in range(num):
     numbers = int(input('Enter values:'))
     a.append(numbers)

 b = sorted(a) print(b) c = int(input("enter value:")) for i in
 range(len(b)):
     if b[i] > c:
         index = i
         break d = b[:i] + [c] + b[i:] print(d)`
```

Comment: What is your argument to claim that your solution is the "best"? By the way, the syntax used is quite difficult to read, if correct.