# Insert element into a list method

Tags: python, class, list

I'm trying to insert a new item into a sorted list, entering the item in the corrected (Sorted) position in the list. Everytime i test my code to see if it's working or not though, i'm getting a message that i'm not really familiar with. i know what i have so far isn't correct, but i'm not able to see what i'm doing wrong if i don't understand the message that i'm getting..
 BTW i'm not allowed to use any built-in list functions

```
]
Your answer: <__main__.SortedList object at 0x1681c10>
```

What i have so far:

```
class SortedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.L = []

    def insert(self, item):
        data= []
        for j in range(len(self.L)):
           data.append(self.L[j])
        return (data)
```

Comment: isn't `data.append()` using a built-in list function?

Comment: Did you use any of the information we gave you yesterday?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571

Comment: The bisect method wouldn't be of any help to me on this, since the program is already wrote. I have to write the code to make it run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is just that your `SortedList` class isn't defining a way to print it. Try adding:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.L)
```

See this for [a discussion of special methods](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-September/031726.html).

Comment: What i have to make run is for example: `if __name__ == "__main__":
    s1 = SortedList()
    s2 = SortedList()print("Inserting items 42, 11, 3, 6, 63, 54, 27, 81, 18, 13, 63 into s1...")
    s1.insert(42)
    s1.insert(11)
    s1.insert(3)
    s1.insert(6)
    s1.insert(63)</code>

Comment: @Will S - Make the change I suggested and you'll be able to see what your output is.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the code, possibly in the wrapper code that your instructor provides is a piece of code that looks like the following:

```
list_object = SortedList()
print list_object
```

`print list_object`, or even `print SortedList()` will produce output that looks like that.