# Using for loops in sorting numbers in list

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop

```
def insert3(x,ss):
    left = [] #why this need to add properly by list, or not it just return the recent result.
    while ss!= []:
        for y in ss:
            if x<= ss[0]:
                return left + [x] + ss[0:]
            else:
                ss, left = ss[1:], left + [ss[0]]
        return left + ss + [x]

print(insert3(6,[2,4,5,7,8]))
```

Is this the correct usage of for loop for the function?

I've changed a bit of it. Is this correct?

```
def insert3(x,ss):
    left = []
    for y in ss:
        if x<= ss[0]:
            return left + [x] + ss[0:]
        else:
            ss, left = ss[1:], left + [ss[0]]
    return left + ss + [x]

print(insert3(6,[2,4,5,7,8]))
```

Comment: What do you mean *"correct"*? Does it work?

Comment: it does work, but its said that y is unused variable.

Comment: Well just *look* at your code - do you ever *use* `y`?

Comment: meaning even i delete the whole for y... s: , the result going to be the same, right?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: it returns same result,

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing complex code to insert into a sorted list? You can just use something like:

```
>>> x = [2,4,5,7,8]
>>> x.append(6)
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Unless you strike a huge performance bottleneck, you're better off just using the features of the language. I like to call this optimising for development effort.

Comment: it's my class assignment, so had to.

Answer (score 0):

Using bisect from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python) would be a good way to solve the problem. Also see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). But a simpler example of what you're trying to do is:

```
def Insert(val, list):
    for i, entry in enumerate(list):
        if val < entry:
            return list[0:i] + [val] + list[i:]
print(Insert(6,[2,4,5,7,8]));
```