# Insert item into case-insensitive sorted list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, case-insensitive

I have a list of strings that is already sorted in case-insensitive order.  I would like to insert a new string into the list.  One way to do this is to append the item and then sort the list, like so:

```
myList.append('Something')
myList.sort(key=lambda s: s.lower())
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to just insert the item in the correct position without sorting the whole thing again.

I found this question: [Insert an item into a sorted list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python).  It points towards Python's  [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module.  But that module doesn't look like it can support case-insensitivity.

---

**Edit**: I tested out several of the answers listed here.

- Appending the item to the end and sorting the whole list (as proposed in the original question) was the slowest.
- Moinuddin Quadri's answer was faster than sorting the whole list, but it was still pretty slow, due to running `lower()` on every item on the list.
- Stefan Pochmann's answer was an order of magnitude faster than sorting the whole list.
- Jared Goguen's answer was the fastest for repeated insertions.  The first time, though, it runs `lower()` on every element.

It was a close call to accept an answer.  In the end, I went with Stefan Pochmann's answer because it was the best for a one-time insertion, and accessing the resulting list does not require accessing a member variable.  However, use cases vary, so be sure to examine all the answers.

Comment: Since it is *case-insensitive* sorted list. Is it allowed to convert all the strings to lower-cased strings?

Comment: Here is a recipe for a class that wraps `bisect` and supports key functions (like `str.lower`): https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/

Comment: You could just copy&paste `bisect.insort` (it's just a handful of lines) and apply `.lower()` to both sides of the `<` comparison.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Well, the final list should still have mixed case, but there are no restrictions on the intermediate steps.

Comment: @Beccacodes What do you mean with final list? At the end of each insertion, or at the end of *all* insertions?

Comment: @Beccacodes Just to understand your perspective: What's wrong with append+sort? Btw, you can also do `myList.sort(key=str.lower)`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann By "final list", I mean the list after inserting the new item.  So in Moinuddin's answer, he makes a temporary copy of the list with all lowercase items.  That is okay because the final result still has mixed case.

Comment: @StefanPochmann There's nothing "wrong" with append+sort.  I just thought that if you have a really long list, it might be slow to sort the whole thing when you can just insert it into the correct location.  (But maybe Python's built-in sort is really fast.  I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good opportunity to practice binary search again (or just copy&paste&modify `bisect.insort`, which is what I did):

```
def insort_case_insensitive(a, x):
    key = x.lower()
    lo, hi = 0, len(myList)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if key < a[mid].lower():
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    a.insert(lo, x)
```

Demo:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for x in 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E':
    insort_case_insensitive(myList, x)
print myList
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E']
```

It's O(n), just like append+sort would be, but only because of the `a.insert(lo, x)` at the end. Which is dead-simple and done in C, so it's super fast. The binary search of course only takes O(log n) steps, so that's super fast as well. The append+sort way would call `.lower()` on all elements and compare them, both of which is much slower. @MoinuddinQuadri's first solution is also much slower because of calling `.lower()` on all elements.

See my other answer for a benchmarking comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) on the lower-cased sorted list as:

```
from bisect import bisect
my_list = ["aa", "bb", "Dd", "ee"]
insert_string = "CC"

#                 convert all the items in list to lower case for
#               v finding the correct location via. bisect
index = bisect([i.lower() for i in my_list], insert_string.lower())
#                bisect based on lower-cased string for  ^
#                case-insensitive behavior

my_list.insert(index, insert_string)
```

where updated content of `my_list` will be:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'CC', 'Dd', 'ee']
```

Comment: You're going to lower the entire list for every insert? (That's at least what this looks like.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes. It is better than performing sorting. Complexity of O(n) is better than O(n log(n)). May be there are other more efficient ways to do it, but I can not think of any

Comment: Sorting would be O(n) as well.

Comment: @StefanPochmann In the worst case, Timsort takes (n log n)comparisons to sort an array of n elements. In the best case, which occurs when the input is already sorted, it runs in linear time, meaning that it is an adaptive sorting algorithm [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Comment: @Arman It's also linear when it's just two runs. Which we do have here! If you append one element to an already sorted list, sorting is going to be O(n)!

Comment: Finding the position should be `O(log n)`, this is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own type to encapsulate this behavior (combined with `bisect` as suggested in another answer).

```
from bisect import bisect

class CaseInsensitiveSortedList:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.with_case = list(sorted(iterable, key=lambda s: s.lower()))
        self.without_case = [s.lower() for s in self.with_case]

    def insert_in_order(self, s):
        s_lower = s.lower()
        index = bisect(self.without_case, s_lower)
        self.without_case.insert(index, s_lower)
        self.with_case.insert(index, s)


test_list = CaseInsensitiveSortedList(['a', 'B', 'cd', 'E', 'fff'])

test_list.insert_in_order('D')
print(test_list.with_case) # ['a', 'B', 'cd', 'D', 'E', 'fff']

test_list.insert_in_order('ee')
print(test_list.with_case) # ['a', 'B', 'cd', 'D', 'E', 'ee', 'fff']
```

You could extend `list` directly and make this a little "more natural" or do whatever else you want with it. This is just an idea to avoid calling `str.lower` on every element for every insert.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with bisect but here is my stab at it. The first function I take directly from the `bisect` page that you linked:

```
def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError

def insert_into_sorted(char, my_list):
    marker = chr(ord(char) + 1)
    spot = index(my_list, marker)
    my_list[spot:spot] = char
    return my_list

x = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']

insert_into_sorted('c', x)

>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: What does this have to do with case insensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

Based on comment from OP, since it is OK to maintain the intermediate list to hold lower-cased strings *(one time operation)*; it could be achieved as:

```
from bisect import bisect
my_list = ["aa", "bb", "Dd", "ee"]

lower_list = [i.lower() for i in my_list]  # list of lower-cased strings.
                                           # one time operation
insert_string = "CC"  # word to insert

# find index based on lower-cased list
index = bisect(lower_list, insert_string.lower())

my_list.insert(index, insert_string)  # insert word in original list
lower_list.insert(index, insert_string.lower())   # insert lower-cased word
                                                  # in lower-cased list
```

where final value of `my_list` will be `lower_list` will be:

```
>>> my_list   # original list
['aa', 'bb', 'CC', 'Dd', 'ee']

>>> lower_list
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']
```

Here we are bisecting the list of lower-cased words to find the index and based on the index, inserting the string into original list.

Answer (score 1):

I see you added test results to you question. I did some benchmarks as well now and get a similar picture:

```
Insorting 20000 words:
 80.224 seconds with insort_sorting
  0.166 seconds with insort_own_binary_search
 70.294 seconds with insort_lower_all
  0.094 seconds with insort_keep_lower
```

You're somewhat wrong about the fast two, though. With larger numbers of insertions, mine becomes faster. About twice as fast:

```
Insorting 1000000 words:
 92.712 seconds with insort_own_binary_search
173.577 seconds with insort_keep_lower
```

That's because the O(log n) time for searching the index becomes negligible and the time is dominated by the O(n) time for the `insert` calls. And my solution has only one of those while the other solution has two.

Another difference is space complexity, keeping an extra list of lowered versions of all strings isn't as good.

Here's my benchmarking code:

```
import random, string, time

#--------------------------------------------------------------
def insort_sorting(a, x):
    a.append(x)
    a.sort(key=str.lower)
#--------------------------------------------------------------
def insort_own_binary_search(a, x):
    key = x.lower()
    lo, hi = 0, len(myList)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if key < a[mid].lower():
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    a.insert(lo, x)
#--------------------------------------------------------------
from bisect import bisect
def insort_lower_all(a, x):
    index = bisect([i.lower() for i in a], x.lower())
    a.insert(index, x)
#--------------------------------------------------------------
from bisect import bisect
def insort_keep_lower(a, x, lower=[]):
    x_lower = x.lower()
    index = bisect(lower, x_lower)
    a.insert(index, x)
    lower.insert(index, x_lower)
#--------------------------------------------------------------

# Generate random words    
words = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10))
         for _ in range(20000)]
#         for _ in range(1000000)]

# Compare the solutions
print 'Insorting', len(words), 'words:'
reference = None
for insort in insort_sorting, insort_own_binary_search, insort_lower_all, insort_keep_lower:
#for insort in insort_own_binary_search, insort_keep_lower:
    t0 = time.time()
    myList = []
    for word in words:
        insort(myList, word)
    print '%7.3f seconds with %s' % (time.time() - t0, insort.__name__)
    if reference is None:
        reference = myList
    else:
        assert myList == reference
```