# fastest way to find insert position for new data into sorted list of dates

Tags: python, search, insert

Let us say I have a list of dates:

```
mydates = [Timestamp('2017-03-31 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-06-30 00:00:00')     
  Timestamp('2017-09-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-12-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-03-31 00:00:00')]
```

And I get a new date and want to know which position to insert it.  If the date is already in the list we assume we will insert it again to the right of existing date.

I.e., `'2016-12-10'` would be inserted in position 0, left to `Timestamp('2017-03-31 00:00:00')`, etc.

Comment: It doesn't look like your dates are sorted.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ good point.  sorry just corected the error...

Comment: So what is `Timestamp`?

Comment: The data still aren't sorted: 30 Jun 2017 is out of order.

Comment: Assuming `Timestamp` is from the pandas library, you should leverage `np.searchsorted`: `np.searchsorted(mydates, Timestamp('2016-12-10'))` — returns 0.

Comment: Sorting and searching form a topic that has been covered extremely well for most of my lifetime.  How did your before-posting research not hand you a solution?

Comment: if the array is sorted why not implement a binary search that return the last value it encounter rather than found or not

Comment: If you have a sorted array, binary search is generally the best way to search it.

Comment: @Prune exactly because of this I ask.. it's such a crowded topic that i found several solutions (python, C, algos, etc.) the point of asking is to see what people think is best out of all solutions out there.  I.e., np.searchsorted from COLDSPEED

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert an item into sorted list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python)

Comment: @Dnaiel There is no one best solution; there are different best solutions for different cases. If you have a numpy array (or something built on top of a numpy array, like a pandas series), you want to use numpy. If you have an arbitrary Python sequence, you want to use bisect. If you have a binary tree, you want to use a balanced sorted tree algorithm. And so on.

Comment: And if you have a bunch of Pandas timestamps in a list, you don't want to jump right to using bisect; you should first ask yourself why you don't have them in a Series, DataFrame, or array instead. Meanwhile, if you're doing tons of inserts and deletes interleaved with your lookups, you might want to ask yourself why you have a list instead of a binary tree or b-tree. And so on.

Comment: @abarnert true, I meant "best" in the context of my data and problem...

Comment: But that's the point—we don't know your data and problem, unless what you have is literally just 5 Pandas timestamps in a list (in which case you should just do a linear search). But you presumably _do_ know your data and problem—so either you can answer for yourself, or you need to give us enough information to answer for you.

Comment: @abarnert true. pending on how answers evolve i'd explain more or not, actually coldspeed function was a good hint but yes generally the more one explains the better the problem can be explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the best you can do to find the location is a logarithmic search. But the details depends on what you have.

Also, notice that even if you improve the search from linear time to logarithmic, if you're using a data structure like a `list` or `array`, the `insert` is still going to take linear time (because it has to shift the rest of the list up). So you may be optimizing the wrong thing.

- For a very small collection, like a `list` of 5 values, you're probably better off just using linear search.
- If you're doing almost all of your inserts in one phase, and then almost all of your searches after the collection is mostly already built, just collect everything with `set.add` or `list.append`, then `sort` it at the end of the phase. This is still effectively (amortized) log time, but with a much better multiplier.
- For a `list` or other plain `Sequence`, use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) from the stdlib.
- For a numpy `array`, or something built on top of it like a pandas `Series`: use numpy's [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). (If you're storing a bunch of Pandas `Timestamp` objects, you probably should be using one of these data structures instead of a `list`, if you aren't already.)
- If you're doing lots of inserts (and deletes?) interleaved with lookups, you may want to switch to a logarithmic data structure. There are many options here, but something like [`blist`](https://pypi.org/project/blist/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sorted list, you can insert the new date and sort the result. You can also use [bisect](https://pymotw.com/2/bisect/).