# Keep sorted list of mutable elements up to date

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, mutable

I can use `sorted` or `list.sort` in python to sort a list that was not sorted before.

If I want my list to remain sorted as I add elements in it, I can use [`SortedList`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) from the `sortedcontainers` module.

However, I find no ready-to-use way to *keep* this list sorted as elements mutate within it.

```py
from sortedcontainers import SortedList

a = SortedList([], key=len) # sort elements by their length.
a.add([3,3,3]) # add in..
a.add([1]) # .. random..
a.add([2,2]) # .. order.
print(a) # [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]] still sorted, okay.

# Now, mutate one element.
a[0].append(1)
a[0].append(1)
print(a) # [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]] not sorted, not okay.
```

I understand that `SortedList` is not responsible to track changes it contained items and to keep the sorting up to date.

How do I update the sorting, then?
Is there a message I can send to `a` so it is aware that I have made a change at index `0` and it reconsiders the location of item `0`, like `a.update_sorting_of(0)`.
Is there another data structure dedicated to this?
Should I write it and optimize it myself?
Should I work around it and `a.add(a.pop(0))` instead?
How would this workaround compare to a dedicated solution?

I can safely assume that mutating `a[0]` has not triggered any changes in other elements in my case (or else I would just `a.sort(key=len)` the whole thing).

Comment: May I ask what is the context of this question? How are you planning on mutating the elements? `a.add(a.pop(0))` seems fine with me.

Comment: There's no failsafe solution to this, except resorting your list everytime you want to use it. You could encapsulate the sortedlist into a custom container class (composition/delegation) and intercept the various `__getitem__`, `append` etc calls but if an element is mutated thru another reference to it, your container will net know about it.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python) - you might want to take a look at the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I am packing objects into equivalence classes. `a` lists equivalence classes. For each object, I test equivalence against one other object in each existing class until I find one equivalent. Then I add it up to the class (`.append`). If don't find one, I create a new class with it. I know that classes contain between n and m elements (n>1) so the algorithm is faster if I keep classes sorted by `len`. This way I maximize chances that a new element finds its class earlier among the ones that still contain few elements. Put it another way: I know that small classes should grow soon.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers If I re-sort the whole list, is there any guarantee that it will not be longer to do that than to just relocate the mutated element?

Comment: @Gerd I think this is only useful when `append`ing new elements to the list, not when one mutates within it, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, may I ask how are you testing equivalence? It seems that you can solve this with a dictionary in one pass over the elements

Comment: @iago-lito you may want to edit your question with your real use case and constraints instead of a generic toy example - there's no one-size-fits-all answer here and the best (or "least worst") solution will be specific.

Comment: How large are n and m, and how many objects do you have?

Comment: @DaniMesejo My objects are graphs, and I know a set of "meaningless" permutations of their labels. To test equivalence between a and b, I need to scroll permutations and permute labels of `a` with them until I find one `permutation(a)` isomorphic to `b`. But I am not sure how dictionaries would help.. would they?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I worry this would lead to this post turning into a [XY instance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/278779). Maybe it'd be tidier to keep my real use case for another post? For instance, I'd be happy to accept your `there's no one-size-fits-all answer here` as an answer if it turns out to be the case :)

Comment: @iago-lito I fail to see how giving more specific details and your concrete use case would make the question an XY problem - quite on teh contrary ;-) - But you're free to close this question and post a new one if you prefer. wrt/ "there's no onse-size-fits-all" answer, I'd have to explain why in greater details, and I don't really have time for this now.

Comment: @HeapOverflow In my case there are 20958 objects, n=2 and m=16. The bottleneck is around the equivalence testing operation that is costly, so I need to save as many equivalence tests yielding `False` as possible. As of today, the naive algorithm takes 8 minutes to run, but only 6 minutes if I sort the whole list of equivalence classes every 100 objects. I am wondering whether there is a more natural way to keep this list always sorted.

Comment: Are you at a higher level already categorizing the graphs for example by number of nodes, number of edges, and smallest/largest degree, so that you test the next graph only against graphs in their category?

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yupe, they all have same `(|V|, |E|)`, although I hadn't thought about smallest/largest degree. This will save a few tests again. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: You could take that further, of course, for example with a sorted list of all degrees. Or with more complicated things like the graph diameter or average distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mechanism to do what you want. Even if you were to resort a list after mutating an element, it'd have O(nlogn) complexity. But because `add()` uses bisect behind the scenes, it only has O(logn). So it's better to do something like you suggested, i.e., remove the to-be-mutated element and readd it. And if there was a function that did what you wanted, it'd probably do something similar behind the scenes, because I can't think of a better way than bisect to place an element whose sorting order may have changed.

```
def mutate_element(sortedlist, index, value):
    temp = sortedlist.pop(index)
    temp.append(value)
    sortedlist.add(temp)
```

You could also further generalise the functionality for various list-mutating methods. For example `getattr(mylist, 'append')` is the same as `mylist.append`.

Comment: This essentially wraps around the "`a.add(a.pop(0))` message". I understand that there is no better way to do that, and that it is already pretty good. Thanks :)

Comment: @iago-lito I saw that, but it was unclear to me whether you were summarising the method while leaving crucial steps out, or not realising that `a.add(a.pop(0))` doesn't exactly do what you want, so I posted the answer. The point of the answer, while not explicitly stated, was that since resorting a list is more expensive than reentering the mutating element anew, even if there was a method to do what you want, it'd probably do something similar to that behind the scenes.

Comment: You got my point :) I also agree that a dedicated, optimal method would essentially do something similar. To get further, do you think there would be a difference between doing `temp=a.pop(0); temp.append(1); a.add(temp)` and doing `a[0].append(1); a.add(a.pop(0))`? That would be a sneaky/dangerous difference, so better be sure X)

Comment: There is no difference, because by the time you call `a.add()` again, the element has been mutated to the new size. But personally I consider the first method clearer in intend. By the way, if you're dealing with a lot of elements, you only have to remove and readd an element if `index + 1 < len(a) and len(a[index]) == len(a[index+1])`. Otherwise modifying in place won't affect the sorting order. But this is specific to `len` being the sorting function, so I left it out.