# Time of sort function, python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

If I have an already sorted list and I add another item (not necessarily sorted) at the end of the list, how much time does sort take to sort this list again?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 5]
list1.append(4)
list1.sort()
```

Comment: Relevant: [Insert an item into sorted list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8024571/10077)

Comment: Python sorts with TimSort, which is O(n log n)

Comment: The sort used by Python is TimSort, which optimizes by recognizing already sorted subsequences.  It should be very efficient for your example.

Comment: @JacobIRR I think that's worst case for TimSort.  It should be even faster for mostly sorted input.

Comment: @hippozhipos don't use `time.time()` for doing code timing, it's not precise enough.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah, I realised that when I ran the code and it have me 0.0 seconds.

Comment: Correct @MarkRansom

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, it's O(n) here. Much worse than `bisect.insort`'s O(n), though, so I wouldn't call it very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure execution time with Python `time` module

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
*** YOUR CODE ***
print("Execution time : " + str((time.time() - start_time)))
```

Comment: `time.time` is based on the OS time, which usually has really poor precision.  It's not appropriate for doing code timing for that reason.  Use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example from BeamsAdept you can also execute both to compare the performance.

```
 
import time

#WITHOUT SORT 
start_time = time.time()

list1 = []
n = 100000
for i in range(n):
    list1.append(random.randint(1, 1000))

print("Execution time : " + str((time.time() - start_time)))


#SORTING
start_time = time.time()

list1 = []
for i in range(n):
    list1.append(random.randint(1, 1000))
    list1.sort()

print("Execution time sorting : " + str((time.time() - start_time)))
```

Returns for example:

```
Execution time : 0.123291015625
Execution time sorting : 58.519288063049316
```