# Find large number in a list, where all previous numbers are also in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to implement a Yellowstone Integer calculation which suggests that "E[very number appears exactly once: this is a permutation of the positive numbers](https://oeis.org/A064413)". The formula I have implemented to derive the values is as follows:

```
import math

yellowstone_list = []
item_list = []
i = 0

while i <= 1000:
    if i <= 3:
        yellowstone_list.append(i)
            
    else:
        j = 1
        inList = 1
        
        while inList == 1:
            minus_1 = math.gcd(j, yellowstone_list[i-1])
            minus_2 = math.gcd(j, yellowstone_list[i-2])
            if minus_1 == 1 and minus_2 > 1:
                if j in yellowstone_list:
                    inList = 1
                else:
                    inList = 0

            j += 1
        
        yellowstone_list.append(j - 1)    
               
    item_list.append(i)

    i += 1
```

The issue becomes that as i increases, the time taken for the formula to determine the value of j also increases (naturally as i is increasingly further away from the start point of j).

What I would like to do is determine the largest value of j in the `yellowstone_list`, where all the values of 1 to j are already in the list.

As an example, in the below list, `j` would be 9, as all the values 0 - 9 are in the list:

`yellowstone_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 15, 14, 5, 6, 25, 12, 35, 16, 7]`

Any suggestions on how to implement this in an efficient manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time to sit down and think about it, and using the suggestions to sort the list, I came up with two solutions:

- ***Sorting***

I implemented @eugebe Sh.'s solution within the while i < 1000 loop as follows:

```py
    while i <= 1000:

        m = sorted(yellowstone_list)
        for n in range(1, len(m)):
            if m[n]!=n:
                break

        if i == 0:
....
```

- ***In List***

I ran an increment to check if the value was in the list using the "in" function, also within the while i < 1000 loop, as follows:

```py
    while i <= 1000:

        while k in yellowstone_list:
            k += 1

        if i == 0:
....
```

Running both codes 100 times, I got the following:

***Sorting***: Total: 1:56.403527 seconds, Average: 1.164035 seconds.

***In List***: Total: 1:14.225230 seconds, Average: 0.742252 seconds.

Comment: You are running the sorting at each iteration, which is of course suboptimal. Instead you should replace your `append` with sorted insert as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python

Comment: Also you can every time start the traversal from the previously found number.

Answer (score 2):

For the "standalone" problem as stated the algorithm would be:

1. Sort the list.
2. Run a counter from 0 while in parallel traversing the list. Once the counter value is unequal to the list element, then you have found one-past the wanted element.
   Something like the following:

   ```
   x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 15, 14, 5, 6, 25, 12, 35, 16, 7]
   y=sorted(x)

   for i in range(1, len(y)):
       if y[i]!=i:
           print(i-1)
           break
   ```

But in your case it appears that the initial list is being built gradually. So each time a number is added to the list, it can be inserted in a sorted manner and can be checked against the previous element and the traversal can start from there for more efficient process.

Comment: I hadn't even thought to do that. I guess stepping back helps

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```py
lst.sort()

for c, i in enumerate(lst):
    if c + 1 < len(lst) and lst[c + 1] != i + 1:
        j = i
        break
    else:
        j = i
```

Basically, the list is sorted, and then, it loops through each value, checking if the next value is only 1 greater than the current.

Comment: I hadn't even thought to do that. I guess stepping back helps.

Comment: Please use ``enumerate`` to get the index and value at once. There is no need to separately increment ``count``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the heads up!