# Using the .insert method to add sub-list in 2D list

Tags: python, list, insert

I have a list below where I am trying to add a [2.5, "peppers"] in a specific place in the list using the `.insert` method:

```
pizza_and_prices =  [
  [2, "pepperoni"],
  [6, "pineapple"],
  [1, "cheese"],
  [3, "sausage"],
  [2, "olives"],
  [7, "anchovies"],
  [2, "mushrooms"]
]

#sort pizza list
pizza_and_prices.sort()

#drawing from 2d list
cheapest_pizza = pizza_and_prices[0]
priciest_pizza = pizza_and_prices[-1]

#purchases
pizza_and_prices.pop()
pizza_and_prices[4].insert([2.5, "peppers"])
```

Since the `.sort()` method by default sorts a 2D list by whatever is first in the sublist. the output should be:

```
[[1, 'cheese'], [2, 'mushrooms'], [2, 'olives'], [2, 'pepperoni'], [3, 'sausage'], [6, 'pineapple']]
```

Now say I am trying to add `[2.5, "X"]` to my 2-Dimensional list called `"pizza_and_prices"` (whilst keeping it in order of prices) using the `.insert` method. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: What exactly did not work as you expected and how?

Comment: Did you read in a tutorial or in the documentation what arguments the `insert` method expects (hint: there are 2).

Comment: Yes I have, but I am coming here for a clearer explanation.

Comment: What did you find and what was not clear about it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'll edit my post to provide more details

Comment: What you are trying to do has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024571/insert-an-item-into-sorted-list-in-python/24714344

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer my question

Comment: Why not? Use `bisect.insort(pizza_and_prices, [2.5, "peppers"])`.

Comment: Was your question how to use the `insert` method in general, or how to figure out the index `4` in order to insert the new pizza at the correct position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give 2 arguments to the `insert(arg1, arg2)` function. `arg1` is an index where you want to add something, and `arg2` is what you want to add at `arg1` index. Keep in mind that the index of data stored at and beyond will be increased by 1.

The potential solution you are looking for is

```py
pizza_and_prices =  [
  [2, "pepperoni"],
  [6, "pineapple"],
  [1, "cheese"],
  [3, "sausage"],
  [2, "olives"],
  [7, "anchovies"],
  [2, "mushrooms"]
]

#sort pizza list
pizza_and_prices.sort()

#drawing from 2d list
cheapest_pizza = pizza_and_prices[0]
priciest_pizza = pizza_and_prices[-1]
#count prices - task 3
num_two_dollar_slices = prices.count(2)

#purchases
pizza_and_prices.pop()
pizza_and_prices.insert(4, [2.5, "peppers"])
```

Answer (score 0):

## .Insert method

**Syntax**

`list.insert(position,element)`

You can loop over the list to figure out the index where to place the given element:

```
ind = 0
for i in pizza_and_prices:
   if i[0] > 2.5:
      break
   else:
      ind += 1
pizza_and_prices.insert(ind,[2.5,"y"])
```